# Can You Pass A COM Interface Instantiated In C# Back To C++?

Tags: c#, c++, com

I have a C++ COM EXE that does processing. I want to allow UI EXEs (including C# ones) to "register" with it, so that when it finishes processing it will pass the result to any of the UIs that have registered.
I've declared a COM interface in C++:

```
interface ICoreToUI : IDispatch
{
    HRESULT OnFlaw([in] IFlawData *pFlawData);
};
```

In my C# program I have a class which inherits from the above

```
public class CoreToUI : ICoreToUI
{
    public void OnFlaw(IFlawData flaw)
    {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

The EXE has the following function:

```
STDMETHOD(AddUI)(ICoreToUI *pUI);
```

I was hoping to do the following from the C# project (IWICore is the COM interface for the core):

```
IWICore iWICore = new WICore();
ICoreToUI coreToUI = new CoreToUI();
iWICore.AddUI(coreToUI);  **<= FAILS!**
```

But the AddUI() call throws a COMException 'Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY).

Is there a way to do what I'd like?

Comment: Yes you can. Since you're using out-of-process (and also possibly different threads in your code) communication parameters must be marshaled across processes/threads. For that you need either a Proxy Stub or in the case of IDispatch interfaces (universally marshalable if you restrict usage to COM/OLE automation types) a type library. Do you register a type library describing the interfaces you use?

Comment: I've registered the DLL but not called regtlib.exe on the TLB. Is that what you mean?

Comment: A tlb must be registered in the registry (32 or 64bit and/or both) one way or another. It depends how you've done your development, it can be embedded as a win32 resource in a DLL that registers it when calling DllRegisterServer for example, or from .NET's regasm, or be external.

Comment: You were right. Registering the tlb using TlbImp.exe filename.tlb solved the problem. Thank you.